# Making an executable file out of a project/solution in VS2015 Community Edition (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm new and trying to get on learning the C++ language but have so far been unable to find how to create an executable file. And whenever I find even close to a solution (although I can no longer seem to find the site that I found one at) I cannot seem to find the tabs or sub tabs that they say to look under. If anyone versed in Visual Studio 2015 could help me find out how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for "Build" or "Build Solution".

And (most likely) you are working within a "Debug configuration", so the .EXE file will be buried in a "Debug" subdirectory of your Project's directory.

[Building in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx)

Comment: I was not sure if that was the problem or the OP was looking for the option to generate a native c++ application or the OP wanted to make an installer. The question is very unclear.

Comment: Well...being new and stupid I had no idea that is what I was trying to do. You have cleared up a bit for me, thank you.